# Each time I retrieve an entity from HIbernate and then discard does Hibernate hang onto any resources

Tags: java, hibernate

I go round in a big loop retrieving a SongDiff Hibernate entity, processing it and then getting the next one.

So I am only using one `SongDiff` entity at a time so my question is will Hibernate release such resources as go round the loop, or could it hang onto it, do I need to call `session.flush()` occasionally or would that make no difference?

I am only retrieving data from Hibernate, I am not modifying any data

I ask because code with *OutOfMemory* Error in this area of the code and I wonder if this could be the problem.

```
try
{
    session = com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSession();

    for(Integer recNo:recNos)
    {
        count++;

        //Get Metadata changes
        SongDiff                songDiff    = SongChangesCache.getSongDiffFromDatabase(session, recNo);
        MetadataAllChanges      mas         = (MetadataAllChanges) SerializationHelper.deserialize(songDiff.getDiff());
        sr.writeDatatoXlsFile(recNo, mas);
    }
}
finally
{
    HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, as you say, Hibernate will build up entity instances - in its `StatefulPersistenceContext`.  It does this to enable it to match an instance if it is fetched again, and to track updates ready for the next commit or flush.

The most obvious option to avoid session build-up is to start a new session, but this isn't always practical, for example due to transactional scope.

The best solution within a single session is `session.clear()`, which will discard any entity instances the session has built up.  If there are also updates happening in the loop, then you will need to do a `session.flush()` before the `clear()`, to push any changes so far to the database.

The other option, at least within a pure Hibernate (non-JPA) environment, is a [StatelessSession](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html), which has no `StatefulPersistenceContext`, so won't build up.  I've tried it a couple of times, but hestitate to recommend it - it seems to be less widely used, so harder to troubleshoot online.

Comment: Well thankyou i did not know it built up entity instances, did not know about clear() and did not know about StatelessSessions !

Comment: Just tried StatelessSession (since I am only reading data) and it did the job for me.